# amending a set of axioms to force every converse to be true

Tags: logic

If we're given a set of axioms $A$, and a set of theorems, $T$ where the converse of every theorem in $T$ is false, does a new system of axioms $A'$ consisting of the converse of every axiom in $A$ guarantee that every theorem in $T' = \{t'|t' \ is\ the \ converse \ of \ some \ theorem \ in \ T\}$  will be true in $A'$ ?

a possible difficulty I foresee in answering is that the converse of an axiom isn't a commonly used notion (that I'm aware of) since we sometimes have "existential" axioms which aren't stated as an implication. but any true statement $P$ can be written as $True \implies P $ in which case the converse of some axiom $S$ that guarantees the existence of some object $O$ would not be "O does not exist" but rather $\exists O \implies True$ which tells us nothing about the truth value of the existence of the object, so it seems as if such axioms will simply "disappear"

any input will be appreciated, I'm fairly new to mathematical logic, have only had a few brief lectures on it, but I'm interested in broadening my knowledge

Comment: "False implies True" is a theorem of any axiom system (at least in classical logic), but its converse is rather problematic.

Comment: good point, thanks! can you think of any "problematic" examples which are not tautologies?

Comment: Can you provide some framework for the notions you use? It could be the meta-language axioms or axioms in the sense of hypotheses in some derivation system or some other formality. The way you pose the question, it is really difficult to answer.

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for the answer, the reason I didn't specify further information if because I was unaware that such specification even exists, I am very inexperienced in this specific area, so I thank you for introducing me to some of these terms, I shall go and do research about them and hopefully post a more sensible questions soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Axioms come from choices we make based on a number of reasons. These include but are not limited to; the theorems we are interested in proving, the formal language of our choice, whether we allow ourselves the principle of excluded middle, and so on. That being said, usually, if not all the time, taking the negation of the axioms leads to a contradiction or a dead end, by the very nature of the process we use to choose axioms.

Answer (score -1):

Allow me to propose a potential counterexample. Take the axiom of choice. It states that you can "create" a set by "choosing" elements from other sets (not formally correct but this is the idea). How would you understand the converse of this? You couldn't simply claim the converse is the negation because then adding it as an axiom to your system would create a contradiction, because both the axiom and its negation are true. Maybe you could conceive of an axiom's converse another way. The axiom of choice could be converted into an implication, "if given some sets, then a new set can be created from choosing elements of the original sets". We can generalize this to "if given P, then Q", and then I would claim this is the case for all axioms, that given some circumstance, something must be true, and this is without proof.

Take a different example, such as the reflexive property of equality, a=a. As an implication then, we can say "if given a, then a=a". But a can be *any* mathematical object, from the integers to some set to a topological surface to some knot, etc. How would you interpret the converse? "If a=a, then a exists"? This is rather trivial, no? Actually, it seems that this is easily provable from the reflexive property itself. How may this be useful? I would claim, in fact, that there is no new information, and with no new information nothing new cam be proven. Say P implies Q is proven true directly from the reflexive property of equality. The converse of the reflexive property tells nothing new, and therefore it doesn't seem conceivable that it is necessary to prove Q implies P. This seems to stand as a valid counterexample to your claim.

It may be possible that adding every axiom's converse is unnecessary to prove every theorem's converse. What I mean is that it may be possible to prove every theorem's converse when adding the converse of some axioms to your system, but not necessarily of *every* axiom. What is sufficient may be some amount less, depending on the system. That's hard to conceive of possibly proving though. One way I see it may be possible is with the use of metalanguages and godel numbers. Although with even that it's hard for me to see a way that it is possible.

I will be upfront and say I'm not terribly confident with the methodology of my answer. I do worry my conception of an axiom as an implication and its following converse isn't valid, as well as my understanding of what it means for the converse of an axiom to give new information or to be provable anyways and therefore not a new axiom. If there are faults in my answer, I expect it to lie within these areas.

Comment: The axiom of choice says if $\emptyset\notin x$ then $x$ is a choice function's domain, so the converse is the obvious truth that if $x$ is such a domain $\emptyset\notin x$.